# unbind parent when clicking child on css

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a bit of difficult in finding a solution for this problem.

I have a hover effect and when I click a li on a submenu the parent li also highlights. Here is a picture. 
[image]

Is there a way to do this with only CSS? I don't mind a jQuery solution, but just curious if its possible with css.

```css
ul li:active > a
 {
    background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
    color: #fff !important;                
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="solutions-link active" id="solutions-link">
     <a href="#" class="left-side">
         <span>Solutions</span>
      </a>  
      <a href="#" class="arrow-up right-side" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuOne">
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
         </i>
        </a> 
     <ul id="hiddenMenuOne" class="collapse first-tree">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Offices</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
              </li>
       </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Lucky, if you use `!important` for every CSS rule you write, you won't be able to use it when you'll actually need one.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the info. is just because there is a bunch of styles on this page already, but I know I shouldn't be using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should move the `:active` style to the `a`

```css
ul > li > a:active
 {
    background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
    color: #fff !important;                
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="solutions-link active" id="solutions-link">
     <a href="#" class="left-side">
         <span>Solutions</span>
      </a>  
      <a href="#" class="arrow-up right-side" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuOne">
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
         </i>
        </a> 
     <ul id="hiddenMenuOne" class="collapse first-tree">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Offices</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
              </li>
       </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```